# Apostrophe in grep Bracket Expression

Tags: bash, grep

I answered a code-golf question here:
https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/89400/57100
My answer:
https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/89421/57100
I got a comment that had a sugestion to improve my answer, but I can't figure out exactly how it works.

The puzzle was to take any input and output just the characters that are in your source code.

The suggestion was: `grep -o '[] [|\'\'greposrtu-]|sort -u`

I get the `-o`, `sort -u`, the first `]` not closing the bracket expression, but I'm a little confused on the rest of the argument to grep. As far as I can tell, the first `'` opens the string, but there isn't one to close it at the very end.  Also, in the bracket expression the first `\'` seems to close the string (if I take out both `\'`s it waits for more input) but also matches `\`

Here are few other more minimal examples:
1. `grep -o '[]']` matches `]` but not `'`
2. `grep -o '[][\']` matches `\`, `[`, and `]` but not `'`
3. `grep -o '[][\'\']` matches `'`, `[`, `]`, and `\`
4. `grep -o '[']` gives an error: `grep: Unmatched [ or [^`

Questions about these examples:
1. Why does `'` close the string, but `]` is after it and that closes the bracket expression in the string?
2. Why does `\'` seem to match `\`?
3. Why does a second `\'` match `'` this time instead of `\` like it did the first time?
4. Why does `'[]']` work, but `'[']`  doesn't?

Comment: A mislead.  _Apostrophe_ **`’`**  has to change to  _single quote_ **`'`**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In single quotes, `\` has no special meaning. Therefore, the argument to `grep` contains

- `[][|\` in single quotes
- `\'` i.e. a single quote
- `grepostru-]` as literal characters, `]` doesn't have a special meaning for `grep` if not being the 1st character inside of `[...]`, and no special meaning for `bash`.

Comment: so grep sees `[][|\'grepstru-]`?

Comment: Thanks! I always assumed if I was using `[ ]` I needed `'` around the whole thing.

Comment: @Riley: You do, as `[` has a special meaning for bash. Or use `\[`.

Comment: What meaning does `[` have? `grep -o [][a]` matches `]` `[` and `a` correctly.

Comment: In `bash`, you can use `$'...'` quoting to write `grep -o $'[] [|\'greposrtu-]'|sort -u`, which might be a little clearer without increasing the length.

Comment: @Riley Actually, `grep` sees `[] [|'grepstru-]`; the `\'` instructs the shell to pass a literal single quote as part of the argument.

Comment: @Riley: Try `touch a b ; echo abc | grep [ab]`: bash uses `[...]` as filename wildcard, so if there are matching filenames, grep sees the filenames instead of the pattern if unquoted.